# Concentration of Wishart matrix

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Suppose G is a $ n\times p$ matrix, each column of which is independently drawn $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$
and the wishart matrix is given by $GG^T$, we know that $\mathbb{E}(GG^T)=pI$. Do we have any concentration probability bound like
$$\Pr(\|GG^T-pI\|_2<\epsilon)\geq...?$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to integrate the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Probability_density_function) over the ball of radius $\epsilon$. You need to ensure that $n>p-1$ if you want to have a non-singular density.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean $p\geq n$? What if we have $n>p$?

Comment: You need indeed to ensure that the event you are computing the probability for has some probability density, which requires a certain number of degrees of freedom. See the last paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Comment: It's possible to give some sense for a smaller degree of freedom but it requires to be careful, the simple pdf will not work out here as the matrix will be singular.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be $p+2\sqrt{np^2}.$ See the result in the abstract of [On the Non-Asymptotic Concentration of
Heteroskedastic Wishart-type Matrix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12434.pdf). The authors gave a more general answer works for the heteroskedastic case.

Comment: since epsilon does not appear in your claim, you might clarify what you mean with "the answer" (is this the variance, which combined with a markov-inequality might get op what they want?)